# CircleCI insert environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I created my first pipeline yesterday and I wanted to replace a placeholder in my bundle.gradle file with the CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM environment variable. The only method I found find was writing my own ‘sed’ command and executing the regex in a run statement. This worked fine to get up and running, since there was only one variable to replace, however this method obviously won’t scale, down the road. Is there a CircleCI feature/orb or other method to do a more comprehensive placeholder/envar swap throughout my project?

```
- run:
    name: Increment build id
    command: sed "s/_buildNum/${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}/g" -i build.gradle
```

**EDIT**

Looking for a utility/tools/orb/CircleCI best practice similar to what they have in Azure DevOps (Jenkins performs a similar feature as well): simply replace all placeholders in specified files with environment variables matching the same name.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens

Comment: For single files, envsubst does the job well. Not very convenient for the whole project though.

Comment: @taleodor that's what I'm currently using inside of a bash script. I'd like to know what CircleCI considers best practice for this type of operation though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [`envtpl`](https://github.com/niquola/envtpl/tree/master) tool with myriad of implementation in various languages.
It allows for interpolating variables in templates with values set in environment variables.

The following described command installs an implementation in Rust.

```yaml
commands:
  replace-vars-from-env:
    description: Replace variables in file from environment variables.
    parameters:
       filename:
         type: string
    steps:
      - run:
         name: Replace variables in build.gradle file
    command: |
      if ! [ -x /usr/local/bin/envtpl ]; then
        curl -L https://github.com/niquola/envtpl/releases/download/0.0.3/envtpl.linux > /usr/local/bin/envtpl
        chmod +x /usr/local/bin/envtpl
      fi
      mv <<parameters.filename>> <<parameters.filename>>.tpl 
      cat <<parameters.filename>>.tpl | envtpl > <<parameters.filename>>
      rm <<parameters.filename>>
```

and use that in other commands or as a part of your jobs. For example,

```yaml
executors:
  linux:
    machine:
      image: ubuntu-1604:201903-01

jobs:
  build:
    executor: linux
    steps:
      - replace-vars-from-env:
          filename: build.gradle
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html#index-envsubst) which provides that basically out of the box.

Depending on your [primary container](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/glossary/#primary-container) you can install envsubst on top of alpine/your distro, or use some image that has that already, like [datasailors/envsubst](https://github.com/datasailors/envsubst).

In that case, you would just need to run configure like:

```
- run:
    name: Increment build id
    command: envsubst < build.gradle.template > build.gradle
```

And in your template file you can have `${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}`, as many other variables directly.